# Help with a function php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, function

I want a function that prints those 2 "print" in the database ( insert intro )  when a button is pressed.

Here's the code:

```
<?php 
$id2name=array();
$x=mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM products WHERE id IN(".implode(',',array_keys($_SESSION['cart'])).")");
while($y=mysql_fetch_assoc($x)){
    $id2name[$y['id']]=$y['name'];
}
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k=>$v){
    print "<br>[".$id2name[$k]."]\t".$v."\n <br>";
}

print "<br>$total<br>";
?>
```

How can I make that a function, to print it in the database when a button is pressed?

Comment: What do you meant with "when a botton its press'd"?

Comment: And what do you mean with "print it in the database"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I got you right, but as far as I understand, you want to write something to the database by pressing a button, right?

Well, to trigger an action by pressing a button, you need a form:

```
<form action="page_to_process_the_db_request.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $total;?>" name="total" />
<input type="submit" value="Wirite to DB!" />
</form>
```

In this example, I assume you want to write the variable $total to DB.

So you post the data to the processing page (which also can be the same one you're on) and there, you look if there's something in the $_POST-array:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['total'])) {
  mysql_query("UPDATE products SET total = ". $total); //or something like that
}
?>
```

Not sure though if this is what you're looking for...

//edit

referring to your comment, I guess you want to write the output of the loop to DB...
At first, you have to create an appropriate structure, like an array:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k=>$v){
    $id2name[$k]['name'] = $v;
}
```

now you can turn the array into a simple string with

```
$serialized_array = serialize($id2name);
```

And now you can write this string to db. And when you read it from db, you can turn it back into an array again with:

```
$id2name_array  = unserialize($serialized_array);
```

Comment: i want to insert or print in database this

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k=>$v){
    print "<br>[".$id2name[$k]."]\t".$v."\n <br>";

total isnt that hard to print just add the variable to the print function, but i have no idea how to print this foreach ~